Converting from VBA using Recordsets to nested Selects in T_SQL stored proc
I have some VBA code (not my code, I have taken on this app development from somebody else) from a Sub that I am trying to convert to a Stored Procedure.  I have been struggling to get my head around how exactly to nest the two SELECT statements (one of which is looking for the latest records using the MAX() function) into the INSERT statement in T-SQL.
maxSql = "SELECT auditId, Max(statusUpdDate) AS maxStatus" _
            & " FROM StatusRange" _
            & " GROUP BY auditId" _
            & ";"
    maxRst.Open maxSql, carConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

    While Not maxRst.EOF
        auditSql = "SELECT ID FROM AuditStatus WHERE audit_id = " & maxRst![AuditID] & " AND Timestamped = #" & Format(maxRst![maxStatus], "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss") & "#"
        auditRst.Open auditSql, carConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
        While Not auditRst.EOF
            statusSql = "INSERT INTO StatusMax (auditId, maxStatus) VALUES (" & maxRst![AuditID] & ", " & auditRst![ID] & ")"
            carConn.Execute statusSql
            auditRst.MoveNext
        Wend
        auditRst.Close
        maxRst.MoveNext
    Wend
    maxRst.Close

I have managed to get the first part of the VBA Sub (not shown in code block to keep things concise) running as a stored procedure however this just required a basic SELECT statement nested into an INSERT and it populates the StatusRange table that is going to be used by the code above.
The SQL statement I believe I need here is a little beyond any I have had to come up with so far, so any help would be greatly appreciated.
I am trying to convert to a stored procedure to speed up the code and get around the fact that MS Access transposes the day and month of the date whenever it can get away with it, despite trying multiple ways of telling it what format the date is in.

Maybe provide sample data and desired result as formatted text tables. Why save data that can be calculated when needed?

@June7 Hi, As I mentioned the code is not mine so I don't know why things are done as they are but running speed might be one reason that the data is saved.  Currently the reports that use this bit of VBA work(1) - albeit slowly - if a copy of the app is made and the tables are converted to local ones.  Running over the network with tables on SQL Sever the code appears to never finish.  (1)They work apart from Access transposing any date that is in the first 12 days of a given month.
Output is 2 columns of ID numbers: the AuditID and the ID of the latest applicable status record.

-- I splitted in 3 parts so you get the idea.
WITH MaxAuditList   AS
    (
        SELECT 
                AuditID
            ,   MaxStatus   =   MAX(statusUpdDate) OVER(PARTITION BY AuditID)
        FROM    StatusRange
    )

,   StatusMaxList   AS
    (
        SELECT 
                ID 
        FROM    AuditStatus     A
        JOIN    MaxAuditList    M   ON  M.AuditID                   =   A.AuditID
                                    AND CONVERT(date, M.MaxStatus)  =   CONVERT(date, A.Timestamped)
    )

    INSERT INTO StatusMax
        SELECT
                AuditID
            ,   MaxStatus
        FROM    StatusMaxList
    ;


Thank you Andy, this is a timely example of using CTEs which  one of my colleagues was suggesting I look into just this morning.
To get this to run I had to make some minor tweaks as I had red squiggles under the columns in the INSERT statement part (Columns not recognised):  Adding ', MaxAuditList' to the FROM of the INSERT statement got it to recognise 'MaxStatus' and for now - I don't think it is what I need in the column, but just to test - I changed
'AuditID' to 'ID AS AuditID'.
That now runs but apparently in an infinite loop, quickly filling up 5GB of log file and falling over.

What it does though is give me another way to approach the problem so thank you, I'll let you know if I manage to resolve.

I don't see any column with the name "ID" in your VB code. I tested with sample data and it works. As I mentioned, I splitter it in 3 parts but it can be done in one block. my purpose was to take you step by step. if you find it useful and/or resolved your problem, please vote.

Here in the VBA: auditSql = "SELECT **ID** FROM AuditStatus WHERE audit_id = " and here in your SQL: 'StatusMaxList   AS
(
SELECT
ID
FROM    AuditStatus     A'

I tried to vote for your post but I am not allowed yet - I'm too noob according to this site.  Out of necessity due to reporting deadlines I have got a workaround suggested by the original developer that uses yet another table of temporary data.  I would still like to get the nested SELECT or CTEs right eventually so will revisit as time allows and if your post is what helps get me there then I will make sure to 'Tick' it.  Thank you again for the suggestion.
